# Spark caching strategy

Tags: scala, caching, recursion, apache-spark

I have a Spark driver that goes like this:

**EDIT - earlier version of the code was different & didn't work**

```
var totalResult = ... // RDD[(key, value)]
var stageResult = totalResult

do {
  stageResult = stageResult.flatMap(
    // Some code that returns zero or more outputs per input,
    // and updates `acc` to number of outputs
    ...
  ).reduceByKey((x, y) => x.sum(y))

  totalResult = totalResult.union(stageResult)
} while(stageResult.count() > 0)
```

I know from properties of my data that this will eventually terminate (I'm essentially aggregating up the nodes in a DAG).

I'm not sure of a reasonable caching strategy here - should I cache `stageResult` each time through the loop?  Am I setting up a horrible tower of recursion, since each `totalResult` depends on all previous incarnations of itself?  Or will Spark figure that out for me?  Or should I put each RDD result in an array and take one big union at the end?

Suggestions will be welcome here, thanks.

Comment: First, accumulators are not reliable when it comes to transformation.

Comment: Why not? I'm just creating an accumulator and using it in a map, then checking it in the driver.

Comment: In theory in this case it MIGHT work here, but the count itself is not reliable due to machine failures and possible recounting. But, since you only care if it is zero, then it probably will work for you. Another note, though. If this is your final code, then this will result in nothing happening. There are no actions being run, so the computation (and thus the accumulator will never trigger)

Comment: I do have an action after this to collect all the results.

Comment: Sure, but here's how this would go down: acc=0, set up a DAG, while hits and acc is still 0 (no actions, thus acc never updated). Then you call collect and you only get the equivalent of one pass through your loop, where it seems to expect multiple

Comment: Aha - I thought you were being dense but it is I who was being dense. =)  Thanks, I'll rework the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rewrite this as follows:

```
do {
  stageResult = stageResult.flatMap(
    //Some code that returns zero or more outputs per input
  ).reduceByKey(_+_).cache

  totalResult = totalResult.union(stageResult)
} while(stageResult.count > 0)
```

I am fairly certain(95%) that the `stageResult` DAG used in the `union` will be the correct reference (especially since count should trigger it), but this might need to be double checked.

Then when you call `totalResult.ACTION`, it will put all of the cached data together.

**ANSWER BASED ON UPDATED QUESTION**

As long as you have the memory space, then I would indeed `cache` everything along the way as it stores the data of each `stageResult`, `union`ing all of those data points at the end. In fact, each union does not rely on the past as that is not the semantics of `RDD.union`, it merely puts them together at the end. You could just as easily change your code to use a `val` due to RDD immutability.

As a final note, maybe the DAG visualization will help understand why there would not be recursive ramifications:

[image: DAG]

Comment: But I don't want to call `count` because that would trigger an extra iteration through the RDD, right?

Comment: You NEED to call `count` or else your code in the `while` would never do anything. And, if you are caching the data, then the extra iteration should be reduced greatly.

Comment: I understand that I need to call an action. My question is about the details of how the caching will work.

Comment: After realizing what you mean, I've updated my question to take your advice.